# How can i prevent Cheat engine for my single player flash games?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, anti-cheat

I have some small flash games in facebook. How can i prevent cheating with cheat engine? My swf file sends the score to my database by php. I just dont want people to hack highscores in my flash games by using cheat engine. What is the best way to avoid these issues?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You really need to accept some of your previous answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can:

this is a really good and easy way to do it.

http://www.riawolf.com/?p=20

Answer (score 4):

2 methods I use are as follows

SpeedHack Watch Dog

http://www.bjoernacker.de/flash/detecting-the-cheat-engines-speedhack-in-as3/

Use this class to determine if the user is using CheatEngine to lower the frame rate

another method would to create a vault class for storing variables ina proxy, this vault will store variables within a different namespace (one that cheat engine cannot alter);

http://troyworks.com/blog/2007/08/05/introspection-in-as3-use-of-namespace/

Comment: Cheat engine can alter anything in memory, I doubt namespaces will change that.

Comment: I've done tests, it can only change values stored in the default namespace.

Comment: Regardless, if the high-score submission is just a post to php without any server side checking, you could just as easily cheat without ever starting the game (by using a debug proxy like charles, or simply posting faked data with wget/curl).

Comment: That's correct yes, but either are pointless unless working together, if youve got a game where you cna change variables but submission is 100% secure then its pointless and vice versa.

Comment: Speed hacking might still be an issue, yes. But with proper server-side validation, the entire game is played on the server as well, meaning you have to reproduce the "actions" required to reach a certain score or it won't be accepted.

Comment: I agree, but it depends on the scale of the game, my thoughts are, add little things like a proxy vault and speed hack and token validation for submissions to put people off attempting to hack. fair enough if the game is for king.com and hold monetary value. but for small scale viral flash games it a little overkill

Comment: hahaha! i just used king.com as an example, then looked at your profile realised thats where you work! weird.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer; you can't.

Long answer; It's a lot of work. One option is to make a server-side port of your game, make sure everything is deterministic, and send over all player actions and validate them on the server-side port (and discard any failing validations).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on game , because some of them You can verify on server , checking user steps , but  You can also record game and save it with scores , than replay highscores to check if games are valid .

Answer (score 0):

I just add some random number to the scores ( let's say 100 ) and then substract it when I show it somewhere. After this I obfusticate the SWF file. So I would have something like : myScores = 100;. If he have 15 scores, the memory will have that 115 number and he will be looking for 15, not 115. Then I substract 100 from 115 and get the real points to be displayed. It is important to protect your swf from decompiling ( there is plenty soft that will obfusticate it ). I also run my own encrypt/decrypt function when sending to the PHP ;)